# What are the different Sampradayas under the "Shanmatha" branches?

Tags: history, tradition, sects

Like the various Vaishnava Sampradayas, what are the major disciplic lines for the other 5 sects: Shaiva, Shakta, Ganapatya, Kaumara, and Saura?

Comment: to clarify, by disciplic lines do you mean sri-vaishnava, gaudiya etc. ?

Comment: Yes sir, that's what I meant. They are also known by the siddhantas... Vishistadvaita, dvaita, dvaitadvaita, shuddhadvaita, acintya bhedabheda etc. But more importantly each have a proper guru parampara listed. I have heard about such differentiation in siddhanta with Saivas but haven't seen or read much for the other mathas. Hence the question.

Comment: They do have the lineage stemming from Adi Shankara.. But I do not know of any specific lineages...

Answer (score 1):

Following are the Sampradays that I know of:

Vaishnava: Rudra, Kaumara, Sri, Brahma and others like Samartha, Varkari

Shaiva: Siddhanta, Pratyabhijna, Natha, Veera

Shakta: Srikula, Kalikula

Ganapatya: Morya Gosavi

Not sure about Saura.