# Are there any Shaiva groups?

Tags: shiva, gods, bhakti, sects

Like ISKCON is a Vaishnava group, are there any Shaiva groups? If I ever wanted to meet Shaivas, where would I find them?

Comment: To ISKCON, both Vishnu and Shiva are demigods.So if they are Vaishnavas, they are Saivas as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the different sampradayas under the “shanmatha” branches?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30044/5212)

Comment: Yes Kashmiri Shaivism is one of them.

Comment: Pl check https://www.saivism.net/ especially https://www.saivism.net/sects/index.asp